# An Alternative to Stopwatch for Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am working with a function that measures login-time of an user. It is required, when the program shut down unexpectedly (lose power, crash, killed by task manager... pretty much everything beside normal logout), the timer/stopwatch need to keep running plus the old value.

Example: User use program 1 min. Computer got blue screen. User login again for 1 more min and logout. The saved `TimeSpan` has to be 2 mins.

My approach to the problem is: every 5 mins, the program will save the value of the `Stopwatch` as JSON object in a file to the local computer. When the user login again, the program will check if there is an json file, that contains value of an already running `Stopwatch`.

I know, that it is impossible to deserialize `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. I tried to wrote a modified version of it, so that I can have "setters" for adding old value.

```
  public class ModifiedStopwatch
  {
        private readonly Stopwatch Stopwatch;
        private TimeSpan elapsed;
        [JsonProperty]
        private TimeSpan Elapsed { get => elapsed + Stopwatch.Elapsed; set => elapsed = value; }
        public ModifiedStopwatch()
        {
            Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            Elapsed = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
        public ModifiedStopwatch(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            Elapsed = timeSpan;
        }
        public void SetElapsed(TimeSpan timeSpan) => Elapsed = timeSpan;
        public void Start() => Stopwatch.Start();
        public void Stop() => Stopwatch.Stop();
        public void Restart() => Stopwatch.Restart();
        public void Reset() => Stopwatch.Reset();
    }
```

In action it will look somewhat like this

```
ModifiedStopwatch modifiedStopwatch = new ModifiedStopwatch();
modifiedStopwatch.Start();
// ....
// Every 5 mins
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
{
    var outer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modifiedStopwatch);
    file.WriteLine(outer);
}
// Crash
// ....
// Re login
ModifiedStopwatch keepStopwatch;
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    var jsonAsString = File.ReadAllText(path);
    keepStopwatch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModifiedStopwatch>(jsonAsString);
}
```

---

My question are:

Is my solution bad or error-prone? (I can't tell)

Is there any existing solution for this problem?

Comment: Why not working with timestamps ?

Comment: try to save timespans

Comment: If your code works, and you want a review of all aspects of your code (not just its suitability for serialization), you may be able to post this on [codereview.se] for a thorough review. Currently, asking if the code is "bad" is off-topic as it requires an opinion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry if my question is off topic. I have this problem and just want to show my code as my attempt as a solution.

Comment: @Cid, Dmitri Tsoy, I haven't thought of it. I will try :)